# CSS transition time not working. Using Revolution Slider with Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, transition

I am using Revolution Slider within my wordpress site. Everything I am adding via the custom CSS is working except the transition time.

```
.titleshadowsmall {
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    transition: text-shadow 1s ease-in-out;
  }

.titleshadowsmall:hover {
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #000;
}
```

Everything I have tried so far does nothing to effect the transition time. I am not sure if there is something within the slider that interferes, or if I am just doing it wrong.

All help is appreciated!

Thanks so much.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Can you create an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate?

Comment: Do you see the text-shadow effect? do you see the effect changes on hover? I mean is there only transitioning issue? or you don't even see the text-shadow effect neither on normal or hover states.. 
In that case try !important keyword for your CSS rules.. maybe it helps

Comment: Yeah, I see the shadow, it even changes on hover. The transition time is the only thing that is not working as it should. It is an instant transition as opposed to the 1s.

Comment: property might be overridden by js.. try using !important ...

Comment: Using !important did the trick! Thank you so much